# How to read a json file from resources without application context

Tags: android

I'm trying to read a json file from res/raw folder, but I'm not in an Activity, it's in a Kotlin `object`. I can't manage to read it without `context` or `applicationContext` which I don't have there.

I tried to create a class where I inject the context with Hilt, but that failed too because I can't inject that class in my object. I'm stuck, what am I missing? It can't be that difficult?

The json file is currently only

```
{
   "spacer": 8
}
```

Perhaps in the future some more parameters will be added. I want to save this value in an object (which contains other values not from json) so I don't have to read it every time it's needed. The parameter is used in a Compose theme.

Comment: If you already have Hilt configured in your project, it's quite easy... But do you want to receive only the String or do you want to convert the String into a data class?

Comment: It would be nice to convert it into a data class, but right now it's just one datapoint and the string would be fine for a start (can parse it manually)

Comment: My bad, I ended up not paying attention to the **main point** of your question, the `object` scope... Unfortunately `Hilt` doesn't support direct injection into an `object`. For certain classes where this support is not available, it is possible to create a custom `EntryPoint` [docs here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported), but it is still necessary to have access to the context, as explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use a context extension function to read your json file from /assets folder:

```
fun Context.getJsonFromAssets(fileName: String): String? {
    val jsonString: String
    try {
        val inputStream = assets.open(fileName)

        val size = inputStream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        inputStream.read(buffer)
        inputStream.close()

        jsonString = String(buffer, Charset.defaultCharset())
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }

    return jsonString
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still need the context to call this function, right?

Comment: this is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) for Context, so yes, it requires context in order to be called (context.getJsonFromAssets(fileName))

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as **Thales** said [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73311940/how-to-read-a-json-file-from-resources-without-application-context/#comment129471254_73311940), you can create an `EntryPoint` to inject anything that Hilt is providing but you'll still need the `applicationContext` to start with, so you will still have to workaround the fact that you don't have it in your object. You could have your `Application` class inject its context in its `onCreate` method, using a 'initializer' function for your object that will both save the `applicationContext` for the use case that you need strings or other resources and also will enable things like injecting any object provided by **Hilt** in your application. I will give you an example on how you would need to change your application class and how your object could look like.

```
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        MyObject.initializeMyObject(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

and your object could be something like this:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import dagger.hilt.EntryPoint
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.EntryPointAccessors
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent

// MyExampleInterface should be properly configured to be provided by Hilt
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface MyObjectEntryPoint {
    fun myExampleInterface(): MyExampleInterface
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
object MyObject {

    private var myContext: Context? = null
    private var injectedDependency: MyExampleInterface? = null

    // make sure the context passed is applicationContext to avoid memory leaks
    fun initializeMyObject(applicationContext: Context) {
        myContext = applicationContext
        myContext?.let {
            val hiltEntryPoint =
                EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(it, MyObjectEntryPoint::class.java)
            injectedDependency = hiltEntryPoint.myExampleInterface()
        }
    }

    fun getResourceFromObject(): String {
        return myContext?.getString(R.string.app_name) ?: "Context not injected"
    }

    fun usingInjectedDependency(): String {
        return injectedDependency?.myExampleFunction() ?: "Dependency not injected"
    }
}
```

I am not a super expert on memory leaks, but if you make sure the `context` passed to `initializeMyObject` is always the `applicationContext` from its `onCreate` method, you won't have any problems with leaks since the `applicationContext` is not released until the application restarts or it is killed anyways.

if you were using **Koin** you could do something like this:

```
import android.content.Context
import com.your.app.R
import org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent.get

object YourObject {

  val context: Context = get(Context::class.java)
  val yourString = context.getString(R.string.your_string)

  // do other stuff with context here

}
```

you should just take care not to store this context object because it could cause memory leaks, you could just use it to get your resource without assigning it to any variables like

```
val yourString = get(Context::class.java).getString(R.string.your_string)
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I can't use Koin.

Comment: It's ok :)

I was reading about the limitations of Hilt regarding this use case.

Unfortunately, I think you will need to implement a workaround but maybe it's not that bad, I will try to give you an example and edit my answer to your question ok? :)